# Is the componentDidMount () method always called in state update?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

In the componentDidMout() method I developed a code to query the internet, but if this query was not done successfully (example: timeout) the user would have the option to update the state and re-query the componentDidMount(). The problem that in the update it only calls the render() method and nothing else.

```
/**
 * Textures List
 *
 * This file is responsible for requesting the server's texture information (api)
 * and printing on the screen.
 * @author David Gaspar
 */

// Importing modules
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { LoadingFailed, Loading } from "./Loading.js";
import { getData } from "../api/textures.js";

/**
 * Stateful Component
 *
 * @augments props
 */
export default class TexturesList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // Loading state
      isLoading: true,
      loadingFailed: false,
      loadingFailedMsg: null,
      // Textures list
      list: []
    };

    // Bind context to tha functions
    this.requestError = this.requestError.bind(this);
    this.requestSuccess = this.requestSuccess.bind(this);
    this.requestTryAgain = this.requestTryAgain.bind(this);
  }

  requestSuccess(data) {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      loadingFailed: false,
      list: data
    });
  }

  requestError(error) {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      loadingFailed: true,
      loadingFailedMsg: error.message
    });
  }

  requestTryAgain() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
      loadingFailed: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { requestTryAgain } = this;
    const { isLoading, loadingFailed, loadingFailedMsg, list } = this.state;
    const { container } = style;

    // Checking datas
    if (isLoading) {
      // It's loading
      return <Loading />;
    } else if (loadingFailed) {
      // Failed in loading
      return (
        <LoadingFailed msg={loadingFailedMsg} eventTryAgain={requestTryAgain} />
      );
    }

    // Success with HTTP communication
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={container}
        data={list}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { requestSuccess, requestError } = this;
    const { isLoading } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      getData("textures", requestSuccess, requestError);
    }
  }

  _keyExtractor(item, index) {
    return item.id;
  }

  // Rending item
  _renderItem({ item }) {
    // Getting item style
    const { itemStyle } = style;
    const { imagePath, name } = item;

    // Returning JSX
    return (
      <View style={itemStyle}>
        <Text>{name}</Text>
        <Text>{imagePath}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  itemStyle: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 150
  }
});
```

Comment: please see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code inside `componentDidMount`, to a function, which will enable you to call the function again in `requestTryAgain`.

```
makeRequest = () => {
  const { requestSuccess, requestError } = this;
  const { isLoading } = this.state;

  if (isLoading) {
    getData("textures", requestSuccess, requestError);
  }
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.makeRequest();
}
```

In your `requestTryAgain` pass a callback to setState, and call `makeRequest`.

```
requestTryAgain = () => {

  this.setState({
    isLoading: true,
    loadingFailed: false
  }, () => {
     this.makeRequest();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount is called when component is mounted (inserted in the tree).

If you want to trigger component update use componentDidUpdate()

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: The componentDidUpdate() method is also a good alternative, but for an isolated feature like "try again" it is more practical to use the setSatate() function callback.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount hook will be called only once in the whole life-cycle of a given component and it confirms that your component is rendered completely.

Since this hook is guaranteed to be called only once so you should not expect it to get the updated state in this lifecycle hook.

I suggest you to use static getDerivedStatefromProps(nextProps, nextState) but here you can only return state so everything you call here should be static and return its value in state for component rerendering
Or componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot). Based on what states you are manipulating on that component.

let me know if I didn't answer what you expected and comment to clear any confusion.

Comment: You should not recommand to use componentWillReceivedProps since method is unsafe and will be deprecated https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Comment: Kevin, Sorry I missed that.